# Magento2: Images showing broken.

Tags: magento2, product, media-images

I have a set of images that I would like to include in the product descirprion part... especially in the long description, however I am unable so.

I insert the photos and then save the page, after which the images are being shown as broken. However in my folders they are showing properly.

any idea why this can happen?

Comment: what do you mean by "shown as broken"? a screenshot would help. Also explain how you add them to the description.

Comment: Please right click or inspect on image & check for URL

Answer (score -1):

If the image have the correct URL, the image will show as you expect. 
I think thats a permission problem.Try to set the pub folder permission to 777.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify how you inserted images. You inserted them directly to wysiwyg editor in admin or you have uploaded them in `pub/media/images` folder and then you called this path in editor.

If you uploaded images by any of above methods and still you haven't found images in front end then you probably have to check your directories' permissions

**NOTE**: permissions should be set to 777

Comment: This is wrong, you should never give 775 permissions to everything. It should be 755 according to the specs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: @Litsher-Nathan Yes it is correct that Magento doesn't recommend 777 permissions but sometimes in some servers, the 777 permissions are necessary E.g. Plesk, GCP etc. So I just told him/her to check after setting 777 permissions to the media folder.